# Get the Title and URL of all the pages opened in MS-Edge Browser

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-edge

I want to know how I can get the Title and URL of all the pages opened in MS-Edge browser. The shell APIs are not supported in MS-Edge browser.

Finally I have tried the UI Automation tools(`inspect.exe`) and found URL, `Title` and `Pid` of all opened pages in MS-Edge browser. These information's are available in "`pane`" control type.

I tried with below methods to get URLs and Titles of MS-Edge browser. But I could not access the "`pane`" control type to navigate further. It always return count as zero.

method 1:

```
AutomationElement coreWindowControl = GetNamedCustomControl(rootElement, condWindowControl, "Microsoft Edge");
// "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow" 
if (coreWindowControl != null) 
{ 
   Condition condPaneControl = new PropertyConditionAutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Pane);
   AutomationElementCollection collection = coreWindowControl.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condPaneControl); 
   Console.WriteLine(collection.Count);
   //Output 0 
}
```

Method 2:

```
PropertyCondition condPaneControl = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NativeWindowHandleProperty, 0x150752); var test = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, condPaneControl);
```

Ref URL:
[Microsoft Edge: Get Window URL and Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967430/microsoft-edge-get-window-url-and-title/32047791#32047791)

How can i read Pane control type and get URL and title of opened pages in Edge browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft Edge: Get Window URL and Title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967430/microsoft-edge-get-window-url-and-title)

Comment: Have you had any luck already with this problem?

Comment: No luck. I have tried Guy Barker code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967430/microsoft-edge-get-window-url-and-title/) but it not working in windows 10 Home edition(upgraded from windows 8.1)

Comment: is your code running with elevated permissions (say via run as administrator) or not?