# Get URLs of pages opened in MS-Edge Browser is not working in Windows 10 Home Edition(Upgraded from Windows 8.1)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have tried Guy Barker's code  from link [Microsoft Edge: Get Window URL and Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967430/microsoft-edge-get-window-url-and-title?lq=1) in **Windows 10 Professional machine**, its working great.

If I have tried the same code in **Windows 10 Home Edition**(upgraded from windows 8.1) machine, its not working and the"urlElement" return null for me. The code not find the "Internet Explorer_Server" class. But the "Internet Explorer_Server" class has found while navigate using inspect.exe.

```
string urlElementClassName = "Internet Explorer_Server";

IUIAutomationCondition conditionUrl = uiAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(propertyClassName,urlElementClassName);

IUIAutomationElement urlElement = edgeElement.FindFirstBuildCache( TreeScope.TreeScope_Descendants, conditionUrl, cacheRequest);

if(urlElement == null)//true
```

I have explore further, the code not capture pane(Spartan XAML-To-Trident Input Routing Window) node in windows 10 Home edition machine. So i could not reach "Internet Explorer_Server" class to find URL.

Is any difference between home and professional edition OS? How to solve it?

Thanks

Satheesh

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
AutomationElement main = AutomationElement.FromHandle(GetDesktopWindow());
foreach (AutomationElement child in main.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, PropertyCondition.TrueCondition))
{
    AutomationElement window = GetEdgeCommandsWindow(child);
    if (window == null) // not edge
        continue;

    string str = GetEdgeUrl(window);
}


public static AutomationElement GetEdgeCommandsWindow(AutomationElement edgeWindow)
{
    return edgeWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new AndCondition(
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Window),
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Microsoft Edge")));
}

public static string GetEdgeUrl(AutomationElement edgeCommandsWindow)
{
    var adressEditBox = edgeCommandsWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "addressEditBox"));

    return ((TextPattern)adressEditBox.GetCurrentPattern(TextPattern.Pattern)).DocumentRange.GetText(int.MaxValue);
}

public static string GetEdgeTitle(AutomationElement edgeWindow)
{
    var adressEditBox = edgeWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "TitleBar"));

    return adressEditBox.Current.Name;
}
```